# MongoDB - Query by sub-tree

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure that the same as the simplified version shown below:

```yaml
{
  some_other_props: { ... },
  systems: {
    sys1: {
      score: 24,
      metric: 52
    },
    another_sys: {
      score: 9,
      metric: 77
    },
    some_other_sys: {
      score: 12,
      metric: 5
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to return all the documents where `score : { "$gte" : 15 }` is true for any of the sub-documents.

The only way I could think of doing this was to get the list of keys in `system` and concat that into some kind of or-statement mess. But it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

I could reformat the document structure so that each system is in its own document... but there's a lot of other information in `some_other_props` and reformatting now would be a pain.

In truth I'm trying to do something a bit more complex. Return all the documents where the difference between the `score` and `metric` of the same system are very different. But before I can do that I wanted to make sure I could just do simple queries on sub-trees as I've shown above.

Can anyone suggest how to query sub-trees in MongoDB?

Answer (score 4):

You should consider storing the sub-documents as an array:

```
{
  some_other_props: { ... },
  systems: 
    [ {id: 'sys1',
      score: 24,
      metric: 52
    },
    { id: 'another_sys',
      score: 9,
      metric: 77
    }]

}
```

Then you can just query  `find 'systems.score' : { '$gte' : 15 }` , and you can also build an index for 'systems.score' if you feel that you need it.

Comment: I couldn't get it how can you reach score inside an array with your notation ? shouldn't it be systems.$0.score ?

Comment: systems.$0.score will be the first array element., system.score will match *any* element. See also: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys

Answer (score 0):

If you now exactly what is getting scored you can make a fat "or" query :

```
$or : [{ systems.sys1.score : { "$gte" : 15 } }, {systems.another_sys.score : { "$gte" : 15 }}]
```

but it seems like a lame way to solve the problem. so my suggestion is make a different catalog for `system_scores` which have a many to one reference to `system_props` collection. That would make it much more easier to query.